# T-SQL Delete rows upon selection

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2008R2, I am trying to call a stored procedure, temporarily store the results in a TABLE variable, and then split that TABLE into several result sets.

I believe the simplest way to accomplish what I want is:

```
SELECT * FROM @MyTable WHERE columnA = true

SELECT * FROM @MyTable WHERE columnA = false
```

However, with the data at hand, `columnA = true` for about 95% of rows, so two filters seems kind of wasteful.  As rows are selected, I'd like to remove them from the table, so the table is smaller for the next selection.

I'm much more familiar with procedural & object-oriented languages than SQL, so here is some pseudo-C# code describing what I want to do.

```
foreach (Row r in myTable) {
    if (r.columnA == true) {
        r.Select();
        myTable.Delete(r);
    }
}
```

Can I do this in SQL?

(I know in C# I'd have to actually use `for (i=Count -1; i>=0; i--)`, but it's less clear for demo purposes.)

Comment: Set based processing in SQL is almost always going to be faster that procedural.  I would suggest just doing multiple selects from your temp table. If performance is an issue, look into indexing the temp table.

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? SQL Server is designed to perform set-based operations, as opposed to row by agonizing row (RBAR). Perhaps there is a different way to think about the problem that is more appropriate.

Comment: I don't want to actually micro-manage iterating the rows myself, but under the hood of SQL's declarative syntax, I believe it is iterating.  It's taking just as long to return the `columnA = false` 5% as it is the other 95%, which leads me to believe it is going through all X rows each time.

Comment: Tables are often indexed which can provide much faster access. The more specific the index, e.g. if the sought value applies to only 5% of the rows, the better the performance. There is no need to go through all of the rows. In the case of a [covering index](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/) the table rows do not need to be accessed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [DELETE statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) with an [OUTPUT clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for the first statement.

```
DELETE @MyTable
OUTPUT DELETED.*
WHERE columnA = ...
```

or

```
DELETE t
OUTPUT DELETED.*
FROM @MyTable AS t
WHERE t.columnA = ...
```

Comment: This is basically what I was looking for, but it appears to be running slightly slower than two separate `SELECT FROM WHERE` statements in this particular instance.  Thank you, Mark.  I think I need to look up a few more definitions before I attempt your next suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider creating a clustered index-based constraint (i.e. primary key or unique constraint) on your [table variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx). Then you could use normal selects and not be concerned about deleting any records.

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (
    uid INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    ...,
    columnA BIT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE CLUSTERED (columnA, uid)
)
```

Note: `uid` in this example is just an artificial uniqueifier. If you have unique columns in your table that are narrow enough for an index key, replace `uid` with those.

This should encourage SQL server to seek the index rather than scan the table. This will likely slow down the insert into the table variable, due to the differences between inserting into a [heap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213609.aspx) and an clustered table.

I would also encourage you to compare any table variable-based solution with temporary tables. The differences can be quite dramatic.